# mongodb distinct with where clause in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a reference collection which has multiple documents like

```
"_id": ObjectId('565555ef4ee29e068f61dd75'),
    "referenceId": "565555ef4ee29e068f61dd74",
    "refName": "abc",   
}
"_id": ObjectId('565555ef4ee29e068f61dd75'),
    "referenceId": "565555ef4ee29e068f61dd75",
    "refName": "def",   
}
"_id": ObjectId('565555ef4ee29e068f61dd75'),
    "referenceId": "565555ef4ee29e068f61dd76",
    "refName": "abc",   
}
```

Is there any possibility to implement mongodb distinct with where or in clause with java driver?
for eg: `select distinct refName from collection where referenceId in [565555ef4ee29e068f61dd74,565555ef4ee29e068f61dd75,565555ef4ee29e068f61dd76]`. I have multiple referenceId's i should get unique refName out of it. How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass a second argument to the distinct method. This argument will serve as the where clause. see http://www.journaldev.com/6320/mongodb-distinct-example-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try in this way?
You should be able to check `equals` condition:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("referenceId", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "565555ef4ee29e068f61dd74"));
List result = collection.distinct("refName", obj);
```

In the same way you will be able to check for `in`.